# Query XML in SQL Server from a field defined as XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I have the following XML snippet:

```
<Plan>
  <CurrentTransaction StartDate="2016-01-01" EndDate="2016-01-31">
  </CurrentTransaction>
  <Transaction StartDate="2015-10-01" EndDate="2015-10-31">
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction StartDate="2015-11-01" EndDate="2015-11-30">
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction StartDate="2015-12-01" EndDate="2015-12-31">
  </Transaction>  
</Plan
```

And I am trying to query based upon the dates, so I using the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS Datetime = '2015-10-01'
DECLARE @EndDate AS Datetime = '2015-10-31'

SELECT [Tran].T.value('(@StartDate)[1]','datetime') AS TranStart,
FROM   [dbo].MyTable mt 
CROSS  APPLY pp.MyXMl.nodes('(Plan/Transaction , Plan/CurrentTransaction)') AS [Tran](T)
WHERE  [Tran].T.value( '(@StartDate)[1]','datetime2') 
BETWEEN ISNULL(@StartDate,  [Tran].T.value( '(@StartDate)[1]','datetime2'))
AND     ISNULL(@EndDate,[Tran].T.value( '(@StartDate)[1]','datetime2'))
```

So in theory, the above should bring back one record, the one for October, but it does not, it brings back them all.

I have tried casting the dates as well as using DateTime2, but nothing works.

Can anyone help?

### NOTE:

Just changed the where clause in the query to:

```
 [Tran].T.value( '(@StartDate)[1]','datetime') BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

and I still get the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @xml XML ='
<Plan>
  <CurrentTransaction StartDate="2016-01-01" EndDate="2016-01-31" />
  <Transaction StartDate="2015-10-01" EndDate="2015-10-31" />
  <Transaction StartDate="2015-11-01" EndDate="2015-11-30" />
  <Transaction StartDate="2015-12-01" EndDate="2015-12-31" />  
</Plan>'

DECLARE
      @StartDate DATE = '2015-10-01'
    , @EndDate DATE = '2015-10-31'

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
          StartDate = t.c.value('@StartDate','DATE')
        , EndDate = t.c.value('@EndDate','DATE')
    FROM @xml.nodes('Plan/*') t(c)
) t
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN ISNULL(@StartDate, StartDate) AND ISNULL(@EndDate, EndDate)
```

results -

```
StartDate  EndDate
---------- ----------
2015-10-01 2015-10-31
```

update -

```
DECLARE
      @StartDate DATE = '2015-10-01'
    , @EndDate DATE = '2015-10-31'

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
          StartDate = t.c.value('@StartDate','DATE')
        , EndDate = t.c.value('@EndDate','DATE')
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    CROSS APPLY MyXMl.nodes('Plan/*') t(c)
) t
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN ISNULL(@StartDate, StartDate) AND ISNULL(@EndDate, EndDate)
```

and check this -

[XML, XQuery & Perfomance Issues](http://blog.devart.com/xml-xquery-perfomance-issues.html)

Comment: This works great, but pardon for being a bit thick, I need it to query across an XML data field within a table. If the data was in a table called xData in a field called myXml, and not a declared xml variable, how would I change the above to use that field instead?

Comment: Yep that got it, sorry, did not refresh the page.